# Как разобраться когда значение передается по ссылке, а когда происходит копирование его в функцию в качестве параметра?

Tags: javascript

Как разобраться когда значение передается по ссылке, а когда происходит копирование его в функцию в качестве параметра?

код для ясности вопроса:

```
function test(param){ // param - это ссылка или копия? 
   // используем param
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копирование в качестве параметра происходит для типов Number, String, Boolean.
Ссылками же передаются Object, Array, Function, и все, что от них унаследовано.

```
var a = { key: value },
b = [ 1, 2 ],
c = function () {}
```

Все три переменные будут переданы как ссылки.